# intellij plugin SDK can't resolve java

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

my plugin project can't find any java classes. 
How can I make my project compile again?
I'm developing on manjaro

project: https://github.com/axaluss/power-mode-intellij-plugin

```
DISTRIB_ID=ManjaroLinux
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.1.2
DISTRIB_CODENAME=Juhraya
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Manjaro Linux"
```

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-192.7142.36, built on October 29, 2019
Runtime version: 11.0.4+10-b304.77 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 5.2.21-1-MANJARO
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1948M
Cores: 6
Registry: 
Non-Bundled Plugins: Batch Scripts Support, CMD Support, dcevm, de.ax.powermode, mobi.hsz.idea.gitignore, net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv, org.intellij.scala, BashSupport, org.toml.lang, some.awesome
```

[image: can't find java.io.File]

Comment: Have you tried to follow [this tutorial](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/build_system/prerequisites.html#creating-a-gradle-based-intellij-platform-plugin-with-new-project-wizard)? It is recommended to use Gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
Somehow the "project sdk" was broken. 
I set it up freshly while I was figuring it out. 
But somehow deleting it and creating it a second time fixed it.